# Is there any acceleration of ions going through two electrostatic grids?

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law, ions

[image]

An ion is shot through two grids, one positively charged, the other negative. **The positive one has much more charge than the negative one**. Let's hypothetically assume both grids have zero applied voltage: their charges aren't moving at all (so no power would be needed, since P=v·I, if voltage is 0, power is 0).

Does the ion experience an acceleration?
If not, why? If yes, how can I easily calculate it?

I have been told there is no acceleration since there is no voltage in the grids, but I thought the static protons and electrons of the grids have an electric field because they are charges, and they accelerate the ion by Coulomb repulsion by the 1st grid and attraction by the 2º grid.

Comment: Do you mean no _applied_ voltage? Because there certainly is a voltage difference between the two grids/plates.

Comment: in my hypothetical example, the charges in the grids aren't moving at all

Comment: That does not mean there is not a voltage difference between the grids. Charges on a capacitor aren't moving either...

Comment: Going back to the capacitor: if the plates were metal and you applied a voltage across them, you would build up charge until the potential between the plates equaled the applied voltage. Voltage and charge are inextricably linked.

Comment: But in my example, would the ion experience the same acceleration as if the grids had less charge but applied voltage producing the equivalent electric field than grids with more charge but 0 voltage?

Comment: There must be a voltage difference between the plates, even if the charges are not moving. It would violate physics otherwise.

Comment: Again - you cannot separate the two. If you apply a voltage you get a charge. If you have that charge you have that voltage. No two ways around it.

Comment: @JonCuster But in my hypothetical case, no voltage is applied. The grids would have a charge: protons and electrons not moving at all, the would have 0 voltage.

Comment: Yet you did work to put the charges there, and you can calculate the potential difference between the two sheets of charge.

Comment: @Dale So if the charges in the grids aren't moving at all (0 voltage), they would still accelerate the ion going through them? –

Comment: "charges in the grids aren't moving at all" has nothing to do with "0 voltage". The "charges in the grids aren't moving at all" is what is called "electrostatic". An "electrostatic" situation in no way implies 0 voltage, nor vice versa

Comment: @Dale Understood. So voltage has nothing to do with using power to exert work on the grid charges and make them move creating a current. Based on this, no power would be needed in an ion thruster for example. Just having two grids with electrostatic charges would already accelerate ions. The charges would be placed in the grids without applying voltage to them, and since P=v·I, if voltage is 0, power is 0 too.

Comment: Voltage and charge motion are separate concepts entirely. Can you edit your question without the zero voltage thing? You can state that the charge on the plates is "electrostatic" to convey the "no motion" concept. Regarding ion thrusters you could ask a separate question.

Comment: alright done, thanks

Comment: Just to say a bit more clearly what other people have been saying (and it seems like OP isn't getting) you can specify the charge on a piece of metal, OR you can specify the voltage. You cannot specify the charge on a piece of metal and separately assert that it is at a particular voltage/potential. If you specify the charge, the voltage is a function of that charge. If you specify the voltage, the charge is a function of that voltage

Comment: You really didn't fix it since you have zero voltage in the question three times still. So I will just answer it as it stands.

Comment: As others have commented, I changed it to applied voltage.

Comment: @AXensen One single point (charge) can have 0 voltage: https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Voltage#:~:text=A%20negative%20electric%20charge%20would,going%20in%20the%20other%20direction.&text=One%20single%20point%20does%20not,defined%20to%20be%200%20V. I don't have a better way to explain myself, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

> An ion is shot through two grids, one positively charged, the other negative.

In the answer below I am assuming that this is correct, that one grid has a positive charge and the other has a negative charge. I am further assuming that there is no other matter nearby besides the charged grids and the ion.

> Let's hypothetically assume both grids have zero applied voltage:

This is not possible even hypothetically. The laws of physics forbid it. Even if the grids are electrically isolated from each other there will still be a voltage between them. This voltage can be found by $$\nabla^2 \phi +\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\nabla \cdot \vec A) = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$ where $\phi$ is the scalar potential (difference in potential is voltage), $\vec A$ is the magnetic vector potential, $\rho$ is the charge density, and $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space.

Since the grids are charged $\rho\ne 0$ and therefore $\phi$ cannot be zero everywhere.

> their charges aren't moving at all

This is called the electrostatic condition, and it simplifies the above equation to $$\nabla^2 \phi = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$

If we further assume that the holes in the grid are very small relative to the spacing between the positive and negative grids, then we can treat the grids as a charged capacitor. For a [charged capacitor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/pplate.html#c2) the solution is particularly simple. The voltage between the plates ($V=\Delta \phi$) is proportional to the charge. $$V=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}d$$ where $d$ is the distance between the grids.

As the ion travels from one grid to the other it will gain KE equal to the potential energy that it lost. So it will indeed accelerate. $$\Delta KE = \frac{1}{2} m \Delta(v^2) = - q V$$

Comment: But note that if the charge comes from infinitely far away on the left, and goes infinitely far to the right, it will slow down as it goes through the positively charged plate, speed up as it goes through the negatively charged plate, and as it leaves through the right side it will slow down over time to reach the exact same speed it started at.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a misconception about what voltage is. It truly has *absolutely nothing* to do with how fast charges are moving inside a conductor - just completely erase that idea from your head.

For the rest of this answer I will define "zero voltage" to be the potential infinitely far away in any direction. Then the voltage on each plate is how much work it would take (per unit charge) to take a charged particle and place it on that plate. So the positively charged plates have positive voltage (because it would take work to move a positive charged particle onto them) and the negatively charged plates have negative voltage.

So the voltage of each plate is *determined by* the charge on each plate. In fact, we have the convenient equation:
$$
V_i=\sum_j C_{ij}Q_j
$$
Where $C_{ij}$ is the "mutual capacitance matrix," $Q_j$ is the charge on plate $j$ and $V_i$ is the voltage of plate $i$. You see, technically, putting some charge on one plate slightly changes the voltage of all the other plates, but for the most part, the diagonal terms of $C_{ij}$ are biggest, and the voltage on each plate is linear with the charge on that plate.

If your question was "does the particle experience any acceleration as it goes through this configuration?" The answer is yes. I can phrase it as "the charges on the plates make an electric field, and a charged particle accelerates in an electric field like $\mathbf{a}=(q/m)\mathbf{E}$. I can also phrase it like this: since the plates are at different voltages, there must be a nonzero electric field between them, because $\mathbf{E}=\nabla V$.

But if you meant "does this setup work as a particle accelerator" the answer is no. The charge does experience accelerations, but it doesn't net-accelerate as it leaves the apparatus. The easiest way to see this is to consider the potential along the particle's path. So $V(x)$. This potential is zero infinitely far away on the left and infinitely far away on the right $V(-\infty)=V(\infty)=0$. And the kinetic energy of the particle is its initial kinetic energy it was launched with infinitely far away (call it $K_0$) minus the potential it gains or loses along its journey:
$$
K(x)=K_0-qV(x)
$$
$V(x)$ goes up to a positive voltage in between the positive charged plates, and goes down to a negative voltage between the negative charged plates, so the particle slows down going through the positive charged plate and speeds up going through the negative charged plate. But there is no net change as it goes out the right side.

So this doesn't work to achieve net acceleration. The way accelerators work (well a really basic kind of accelerator), is to use time-varying voltages/charges on the conductor. So imagine having one set of plates, which you negatively charge. Then when the positive charge gets to the middle, take away the negative charge, leaving the charge you wanted to accelerate with more energy than it had before but in a place with zero voltage.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading. In reality, we have some particle source (e.g. electrons) close to a cathode, and some distance away from it an anode. The electron is accelerated to the anode, and passes it (if there is a hole). After passing it, the electric field is practially zero since any other potential is far away, and the electron continues with constant speed. This is the basis for cathode ray tubes, and the low energy beam transfer in a lot of particle accelerators -- time-varying voltages are used at later stages.

Comment: @a20 The question asked about an ion being shot _through_ this arrangement of capacitors. I think it's clear from this answer that if the ion starts out in the center of the positively charged plate, and ends up in the center of the negatively charged plate, it will be at a higher velocity (it moved from a higher potential energy to a lower one). In the arrangement you describe, the final energy is determined only by the voltage on the cathode. The "anode" is often for focusing or preventing space charge voltage by removing charge. It does not net accelerate the charge as you seem to imply.

Comment: @a20 edit: A _much_ more relevant purpose for the anode you're describing is to determine the direction that the electrons fly.

Comment: They are accelerated by the electric field, which arises due to the potential differences (to be precise, between the electron emitter and the anode). The anode will not focus the beam, because of the hole you will have nonlinear equipotential lines close to it, which will lead to a **defocusing** of the beam. For focusing, one needs more parts, e.g. an einzel lens (three electrodes), or a wehnelt (which is in principle what I described above, e.g. emitter, positive plate, negative plate). Also, simple electrostatic LEBTs such as this have no space charge compensation (beam loss != SCC)

Comment: @a20 clearly you know more than me about electron guns. The third suggestion in my second comment seems to be the only one that was correct at all. Otherwise we seem to have the question of does "accelerate" mean "is there any acceleration at any point in time" versus "is the particle left with higher velocity than it started after passing through" (in the sense of "particle accelerator"). In the former case, yeah, all charged surfaces will induce an acceleration on all free charges.