# If a Gaussian surface is assumed in a non-uniform electric field and charge enclosed is zero, is the net electric flux coming out still zero?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Assume a Gaussian surface in a non-uniform electric field that is directed along X-axis. Say the field is getting weaker as we go along positive X direction and it's constant along Y and Z directions. Then, if the Gaussian surface is a cube and charge enclosed is zero, the electric flux coming into the surface is more than that flowing out. So, shouldn't the net electric flux be non-zero contradicting Gauss's law?

Does it mean such an electric field is impossible without a charge being distributed along the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains a contradiction. Basically the last sentence of your question is completely right. If $\mathbf{E}=f(x)\hat{x}$, then
$$
\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=f'(x)\neq 0
$$
So in order to have an electric field that is only in the $\hat{x}$ direction and changes in magnitude with $x$, there must be charge present. With this electric field, Gaussian surfaces have nonzero flux because there is charge inside of them.

If there is no charge in a Gaussian surface, the net flux through it is zero, and this electric field is not possible. This is an absolute law. There are no exceptions.

This question reminds me of [this other one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762559/is-there-any-acceleration-of-ions-going-through-two-electrostatic-grids), where OP thought they could specify the charge on a conductor *and the voltage*. Just like in that situation, the electric field (or rather the divergence of the electric field) is *determined by the charge*. You cannot freely choose any electric field and separately say there is no charge present.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the equation you use is actually also Gauss's Law, but in differential form.